# Use old secret_key_base in rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm doing bump in the rails version from 5.1 to 5.2. My project uses the env variables and the secret_key_base in the old way, and my client wants to maintain that behaviour. Unfortunately, when i deploy to production this upgrade, i keep getting

```
ArgumentError: Missing 'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment, set this string with 'rails credentials:edit'
```

Is there a way to "disable" this new credentials and keep using secrets the old way? I don't want to create neither the credentials or the master.key, is that possible or i'm force to do it weather i like it or not?

Comment: How does your `secrets.yml` look like? There's a section with `production` which I think it's commented out. Uncomment it and use the env var there and you should be good to go.

Comment: Is not commented, i'm using an env variable to set that secret_ley_base, but now with the credentials the error that i commented appears